# UIView Delta Time

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview

I'm animating a UIView by updating its anchorpoint 60 times a second using an NSTimer.
The location of the UIView changes depending on its angle, so it always appears to be down relative to the device...
However, the NSTimer doesn't fire *precisely* 60 times a second. It's always a little off, causing jerky animation. I've searched this a lot, I know a bit about delta time, but I don't know how to apply it to my situation.

Here's the movement code I'm using:

```
float rotation = 0;

if (leftSideIsBeingHeldDown) {
    rotation += (0.05f/rotationFactor);
} else if (rightSideIsBeingHeldDown) {
    rotation -= (0.05f/rotationFactor);
}
movementX += -sinf(rotation);
movementY += -cosf(rotation);

float finalX = 0.0001 * movementX;
float finalY = 0.0001 * movementY;

mapView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(finalX, finalY);

mapView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rotation);
```

Does anyone know how to apply delta time to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to record the time you last rotated, and the difference in time between then and now, and use that to work out a factor, which you can use to adjust the rotation and x/y values.

for example:

```
NSDate now = [NSDate now];
timeDiff = now - lastRotateTime;
factor = timeDiff / expectedTimeDiff;

x = x + xIncrement * factor;
y = y + yIncrement * factor;

angle = angle + angleIncrement * factor;
```

There are many better examples on game dev forums, which explain it in more detail.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look into the [CADisplayLink](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CADisplayLink_ClassRef/Reference/Reference.html) class which provides you a timer that is tied to the display refresh rate. It should be a better solution than an `NSTimer` in this case.

Additionally, you need to remember the time of each "tick" and calculate the rotation or movement that should have been done since the last tick. For example (pseudo-code):

```
- (void)displayLinkTick:(id)sender
{
    NSTimeInterval timespan;
    NSDate *now;

    now = [NSDate date];
    if (myPreviousTick) {
        timespan = [now timeintervalSinceDate:myPreviousTick];
    } else {
        // The very first tick.
        timespan = 0;
    }

    // Calculate the angle according to the timespan. You need a
    // value that specifies how many degrees/radians you want to
    // revolve per second and simply multiply that with the timespan.
    angle += myRadiansPerSecond * timespan;
    // You'd do the same with the position. I guess this involves
    // minor vector math which I don't remember right now and am
    // too lazy to look up. You need to have a distance per second
    // which you multiply with the timespan. Together with the
    // direction vector you can calculate the new position.

    // At the end, remember when this tick ran.
    [myPreviousTick release];
    myPreviousTick = [now retain];
}
```